# Hello, how can I solve problem in fragment - get edit text to string

Tags: java, android

```
private void showAllUserData() {

    Intent validation = getActivity().getIntent();
    String user_username = validation.getStringExtra("username");
    String user_email = validation.getStringExtra("email");
    String user_password = validation.getStringExtra("password");
    String user_name = validation.getStringExtra("name");


    fullNameLabel.setText(user_name);
    userNameLabel.setText(user_username);
    fullname.getEditText().setText.toString(user_name);
    email.getEditText().setText.toString(user_email);
    password.getEditText().setText.toString(user_password);

}}
```

My get all user data method has a problem here, in the edit text to string section, I don't how to use it in a fragment.

here is how my code looks like in android studio

[image: here is how my code looks like in android studio]

Comment: Can you share your full fragment code?

Comment: Can you share your fragment xml code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are `full_name_profile`, `email_profile` and `password_profile` EditTexts in your XML layout? Because in that case, the variables `fullname`, `email` and `password` are already EditTexts and you can just remove `getEditText()` from your code and set the text like this: `fullname.setText(user_username)`